# How to populate AutoCompleteTextView inside a ListView from SQLite database efficiently?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, dataadapter, autocompletetextview

I am populating the ListView from my Custom DataAdaptor. I have a layout defined for each item/row of the listview. Inside that ListView i have an AutoCompleteTextView. I need to bind it with data from SQLite database. Actually this AutoCompleteTextView will list categories & these categories will come from a SQLite Table.I can bind it in my Custom DatAdapeter class inside getView() but i don't know how to avoid the multiple calls to the SQLite database?

> As the categories will remain the same for each row so i want to get
>   the Categories just once from the database & bind it with
>   AutoCompleteTextView in each row.

Can someone guide me how to do it?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid multiple database calls ..

You can fetch data in cursor from database in your activity's `onCreate()` then using `CursorAdapter` or `SimpleCursorAdapter` bind it (using setAdapter) to `AutoCOmpleteTextView` in your list Adapter's `getView()`..

This example will help you lot [Using AutocompleteTextView with SQLite and CursorAdapter](http://hello-android.blogspot.com/2011/06/using-autocompletetextview-with-sqlite.html)

Comment: OOPS! why i was not think about this solution? GREAT THANKS.